# Broken WordPress admin layout after move to root

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress site which was running under a subdirectory like www.mysite.com/development

But after the development of the site was done I moved it to the root.

I copied the files from the sub-folder to the root and updated the MySQL database with the new path.

The result is a completely broken and useless admin panel([Screenshot of the admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaVVu.png)), and I've no clue what to check for now. I've also tried a few plugins from WordPress which should update the database.

It seems like the "dash" icons are missing?

```
    .dashicons-admin-appearance::before {

    content: "\f100";

}
```

I've also checked the console in the browser, and it seems like jquery is missing several places? [Screenshot of console debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX9sD.png)

I'm pretty confused where to start, I thought this would be a relly simple task to move the site from a sub-folder to the root. All ideas and inputs are really appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are missing static content that is fetched by the client after the PHP has processed the page. If so then take a look at your browser's debug console and/or networking tab. My bet is that you have a bunch of 404 errors referencing content in the (now deleted) /development folder

Comment: Also, as a debugging step, I recommend duplicating the code back into the /development folder (but still load the site from the root location). If the problem is broken links then doing this should get the site "working", then you can slowly remove content from the duplicate to find what is still being referenced. Get me?

Comment: @mattavatar Thanks for the input. I've created the older /development folder again with the old content, but it did not change anything. And there are no 404 errors. But thank for the suggestions. It is actually the admin page which is the worst.

Comment: Well, I am stuck on 404 errors. I think you have them. To be clear, the admin pages rely on static content just the same as the public pages -- and your screenshot makes it look like your problem is that youre missing the image files and css files for the admin page. Please confirm one more time that you see no errors in your developer-tools console: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open